# FATAL Exception main while displaying images in listview

Tags: android, image, parsing, listview

I am at beginner level, i am populating listview with different remote images and text in an android app. I am using adapter to populate listview and AsynTask to load images. But i am facing two problems and tried most since many days but unfortunately can't success. First problem is that first image and text appears in first row of listview and disappears than second row being populated with second image and text and also disappears and similarly each rows appears with images and text and disappears. Second problem is that when final row appears than app crashes and stopped running giving below exception:

```
11-01 20:03:56.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29665): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 20:03:56.449: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29665): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my main class:

```
public class ParseImagesActivity extends ListActivity {
String myURL;
String xml; 
 Document doc; 
 NodeList nodes; 
 //int i=5;
 int j=0;
 int equal;
 int h;
 String[]  length = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",null};

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);

        xml = XmlParser.getXML("http://url.com");
         doc = XmlParser.XMLfromString(xml);
        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        Element g = (Element)nodes.item(j);
        startParsing(XmlParser.getValue(g,"thumb"));

    }
```

In main class i am calling startParsing method passing it a url..1 to access first image by function XmlParser.getValue(g,"thumb") which return url from XmlParser class. startParsing method is:

```
private void startParsing(String url) {  

     new backgroundLoadListView().execute(url);

 }

public class backgroundLoadListView extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     if(j<nodes.getLength()){
   setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(ParseImagesActivity.this, R.layout.row, length));
            Log.e("post Execute","post execute="+j);

        equal=j;
        j++;
        Element h = (Element)nodes.item(j);
        startParsing(XmlParser.getValue(h,"thumb"));
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.e("do in back","do in back="+j);
         String url = params[0];
        preLoadSrcBitmap(url);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here i am calling MyCustomerAdapter constructor and in postExecute method i am calling startParsing method passing url2,3,4,...etc to access other images. MyCustomAdapter class and preloadSrcBitmap method are:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Bitmap bm;


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            String[] objects) {
        //
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        bm = srcBitmap;
        Log.e("my customer adapter","my adapter"+j);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        View row = convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);  
                                  }

        Log.e("getview",j+"calls");
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.weekofday);
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if(j<nodes.getLength())
        {
            if(equal==position)
            {
                Log.e("text view calls",""+equal);
            Element f = (Element)nodes.item(equal);

        label.setText(XmlParser.getValue(f, "title"));
        icon.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

        }
        return row;
        }   

}

Bitmap srcBitmap;
private void preLoadSrcBitmap(String url){
    //Log.e("preloadsrcbitmap","preloadsrcbitmap="+j);
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

    srcBitmap = LoadImage(url, bmOptions);

}



/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    String selection = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, selection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}

private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options)
{       
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;       
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }

    return bitmap;                  
}

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    URL url = new URL(strURL);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();    

        }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
    }

    return inputStream; 
}
```

And thanks very much to the peoples helping me with mentioned problems. I can't figure them out.

Comment: Provide more of the stacktrace -  next line will tell you where NPE happened ( then queston is mostly answered automatically )

Answer (score 0):

Anything that updates the UI (interacts with the Activity) with an AsyncTask needs to have the following structure (outline because I haven't done this in awhile :P):

```
//AsyncTask starts here
//code that doesn't run on the UI thread
myASyncTask.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    //update your UI stuff here
    };
//do more non-UI stuff here
```

It looks like you're trying to update ImageViews and TextViews synchronously within an AsyncTask method.  This will cause Fatal Errors.  Try the code above :)

Hope this helps!  Let me know if you need more clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pheonixblade. Can you please provide me guidance where to implement that code which you have described?

Comment: I have made some changes in my code and now it doesn't give Fatal errors but still images and text in listview rows disaapear.

Comment: you need to call your update method inside of the runOnUiThread snippet.  You need to also make sure you update your list adapter, or it will not show the new views.  I remember having issues with this myself... I suggest drawing on a piece of paper exactly what happens with the XML/image data in each stage.  Make sure you are not touching anything in the front-facing activity within the ASyncTask outside of your runOnUiThread.  This includes property assignments, variable accesses, etc.